Blazor server-side file upload to remote location
I want to upload file to a remote file server that is protected with username and password
in ASP.NET i was suggested to use
SecurityManager sm = new SecurityManager();
sm.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sharedUsername"];
sm.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sharedPassword"];

sm.StartImpersonation();

if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/xxxxxx/" + filename.Trim())))
//do some stuff

sm.EndImpersonation();

But in the blazor server-side (.NET8), this doesnt work
So if somebody has any idea, please, dont be shy :)

The file server is protected by which mode? Windows or else? It only support specific use to access or else?

file server is windows based, with access limited only to the specific user for the specific folder. I have user credentials i just dont know how to correctly implement the connection.

I suggest you could use the WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync to achieve your requirement, by using this method you could set the username and password to get the token by using the advapi32.dll.
You could write the helper method like below and use the blazor inputfile to upload the file.
More details, you could refer to below codes:
public class WindowsImpersonationHelper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IntPtr _userHandle;
    private readonly WindowsIdentity _windowsIdentity;

    public WindowsImpersonationHelper(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        _userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        var logonType = 2; // LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE
        var logonProvider = 0; // LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT

        var result = LogonUser(username, domain, password, logonType, logonProvider, out _userHandle);
        if (!result)
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        _windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(_userHandle);
    }

    public async Task<bool> RunAsUserAsync(Func<Task> action)
    {
        try
        {
            await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync(_windowsIdentity.AccessToken, async () =>
            {
                await action();
            });
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _windowsIdentity?.Dispose();
        if (_userHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(_userHandle);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private extern static bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
}

Blazor:
<InputFile OnChange="HandleFileSelected"   />
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedFileName))
{
    <p>Selected file: @selectedFileName</p>
 
}

@code {

    private string selectedFileName;
  

    private async void HandleFileSelected(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = e.File;
        selectedFileName = file.Name;
        var folderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "UploadedFiles");    
        if (file != null)
        {
            var tempFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, file.Name);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            // Replace these with your actual domain, username, and password
            string domain = "domain";
            string username = "username";
            string password = "password!";

            try
            {
                using (new WindowsImpersonationHelper(domain, username, password))
                {
                    // Perform the file upload or any operation requiring impersonation here
                    string remotePath = @"\\remoteserver\test\" + file.Name;
                    System.IO.File.Copy(tempFilePath, remotePath, overwrite: true);
                }

             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             }
            finally
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(tempFilePath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(tempFilePath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

